# User unable to access and execute stored procedure via my app

Tags: sql-server, database, connection-string

I have currently got an application that uses Integrated Security for the connection string to a SQL Server database. On my database side I have set up an Login via an AD group that has a Role assigned to it. The role has execute permission to all the procedures needed.

For some reason, it is not allowing for the users in the AD Group to perform any request to the database and the application crashes.

The connection string has been done like this:

```
connectionString="Data Source=test;Initial Catalog=test; Integrated Security=True
```

Could you advise please?

Comment: There will be no code associated with this as its just a connection between database and application.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the Login or Group as a User within the target database.

Comment: This is not enough. The user probably needs execute permission on the proc.

Comment: According to original post, Login is assigned to a Role and the Role already has exec permissions on proc.

Comment: The group has been set as a user. The group then has a role assigned to it which has all the permissions to execute the stored procedures.

Comment: Please modify your original post with more details including the actual error you're seeing